# cfheader code 500 instead of 410 gone

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to show status code 410, but instead it shows status code 500.  Can anyone explain why?

I am using IIS7 and ColdFusion 9. This is my code:

```
<cfheader statuscode="410" statustext="Gone" />
<cfinclude template="../cgi-bin/file_not_found.cfm">
<cfabort>
```

This is my application.cfc file:

```
<cfcomponent output="No">
    <cfinclude template="f/login.cfm" >
    <!--- <cfinclude template="f/security.cfm"> --->
    <cfset this.clientmanagement=true>
    <cfset this.sessionmanagement="yes">
    <cfset this.name="UL">
    <cfset this.clientstorage="cookie">
    <cfset this.setclientcookies="true">

    <cffunction name="OnSessionStart">
        <!--- 1111 --->
        <!--- set defualt buyer session anyway! --->
        <cfset SetDefaultBuyer()>
        <cfset SetDefaultSeller()>
        <!--- define session and client mylist --->
        <cfset session.mylist="">
        <!--- <cfif isdefined("client.mylist")><cfset session.mylist=client.mylist><cfelse><cfset session.mylist=""><cfset client.mylist=""></cfif> --->

       <!--- trying to login as user --->
      <cf_LoginCookies>

      <cfif FindNoCase('pa_',CGI.PATH_TRANSLATED) AND ( NOT ISDefined("session.user.status")) >
         <cflocation addtoken="No" url="#Application.URL#/p_login/login_form.cfm">   
      </cfif>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="OnApplicationStart">
      <cfinclude template="including/global_variables.cfm">
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean">
      <!---
     <cfif CGI.REMOTE_ADDR IS "81.218.200.52">    
     <cfelse>
        <cfoutput><br> <br> <br>
        <h2 align="center">Sorry,<br>
        We are in process of maintenance.<br>
        Please try at 10:00 AM<br>

        Now is #Timeformat(now())#</h2></cfoutput>
        <cfabort>   
    </cfif>
    --->
                <!--- 2222 --->

                <!--- Neged atacks --->

                <cfparam name="CGI.QUERY_STRING" default="222">

                 <cfif FindNoCase('Declare',CGI.QUERY_STRING)>

                <cfabort>

                </cfif>

                <cfif Len(CGI.QUERY_STRING) GT 400>

                <cfabort>

                </cfif>





                <!--- im menase lirot MyUL bli lihiot LogIn --->

                <cfif FindNoCase('pa_',CGI.PATH_TRANSLATED) AND ( NOT ISDefined("session.user.status")) AND ( NOT ISDefined('form.type') )>

                <cflocation addtoken="No" url="#Application.URL#/p_login/login_form.cfm">

                </cfif>





                <cfreturn True>

</cffunction>

                        <cfif CGI.HTTP_HOST IS not "192.168.1.223">

                    <cffunction name="onError">



                        <cfargument name="Except" required=true/>

                        <!--- Log all errors in an application-specific log file. --->   

                        <!--- define message --->

                        <cfif isdefined('except.cause.cause.message')>

                        <cfset message=except.cause.cause.message>

                        <cfelseif isdefined('except.cause.message')>

                        <cfset message=except.cause.message>

                        <cfelse>

                        <cfset message=''>

                        </cfif>



                        <!--- define template --->

                        <cfif isdefined('except.cause.tagcontext')>

                        <cfset template=except.cause.tagcontext[1].template>

                        <cfset line=except.cause.tagcontext[1].line>

                        <cfelse>

                        <Cfset template=''>

                        <Cfset line=''>

                        </cfif>



                      <!--- define second template --->

                     <cfif arraylen(except.cause.tagcontext) gt 1>

                     <cfset template= template & ',' & except.cause.tagcontext[2].template>

                     <cfset line=line & ',' & except.cause.tagcontext[2].line>

                     <cfelse>               

                     </cfif>



                       <!--- define third template --->

                     <cfif arraylen(except.cause.tagcontext) gt 2>

                     <cfset template= template & ',' & except.cause.tagcontext[3].template>

                     <cfset line=line & ',' & except.cause.tagcontext[3].line>

                     <cfelse>               

                     </cfif>



                         <cfset text="Message: #message# , template:#template# , line:#line#">





                    <!---  define sql --->

                    <cfif isdefined('except.cause.sql')>

                    <cfset text=text & ' , sql:' & except.cause.sql>

                    </cfif>





                      <cflog file="MyAppLog" type="error" text="#text# ,client_ip: #cgi.REMOTE_ADDR# , url:#cgi.HTTP_URL#,ref:#cgi.HTTP_REFERER#">

                        <cfinclude template="/including/error.cfm">

                       <!---  <cflocation addtoken="false"  url="#application.url#/including/error.cfm?message=#message#&template =#template#&line=#line#">

                        ---> </cffunction></cfif>





<cffunction name="onRequest" returnType="boolean">

<cfargument name="targetPage" type="String" required=true/>



<cfinclude template="f/security.cfm">

<cfinclude template="#Arguments.targetPage#">



<cfreturn True>  

</cffunction> 





<!---

    <cferror type = "request"  

        template = "../including/error.cfm"

        mailto = "dtpozner@gmail.com"> --->



<cffunction name="onRequestEnd" returnType="boolean">

<cfreturn True>

</cffunction>



</cfcomponent>
```

and this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <rewrite>

            <rules>

                <clear />

                <rule name="C page detailed">

                    <match url="^(.*)/(.*)-(.*)/cc_(.*)_s(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/c_page/index.cfm?id={R:4}&amp;cat_id={R:5}&amp;manuf={R:2}&amp; model={R:3}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="C page less detailed">

                    <match url="/cc_(.*)_s(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/c_page/index.cfm?id={R:1}&amp;cat_id={R:2}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="C Pages">

                    <match url="/cc_(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/c_page/index.cfm?id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="B Page Pnumbers" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="/bb_(.*)_pn(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="category/c_index.cfm?cat_id={R:1}&amp;pnumber={R:2}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="B Pages">

                    <match url="/bb_(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="category/c_index.cfm?cat_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="TM Guide B Pages">

                    <match url="/tmm_(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="tm_guide/cat_view.cfm?cat_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="TMGuide C Page">

                    <match url="/tmc_(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="tm_guide/model.cfm?model_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="T&amp;M-Buying-Guide" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^T&amp;M-Buying-Guide" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="tm_guide/index.cfm" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="Home Page">

                    <match url="^$" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/homepage/index.cfm" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="A Page Pnumbers">

                    <match url="/aa_(.*)_pn(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="category/m_index.cfm?main_id={R:1}&amp;pnumber={R:2}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="A Pages">

                    <match url="/aa_(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="category/m_index.cfm?main_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="GogglePageModeID">

                    <match url="/gm_model_id(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="model/model_index.cfm?model_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="GoogleModelManufCat">

                    <match url="/gmm_model(.*)_manuf(.*)_cat(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="model/model_index.cfm?model_id={R:1}&amp;manuf={R:2}&amp;cat={R: 3}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b_pages" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^b(\d+?)p(\d+?)pr(\d+?)-.*\.htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="category/c_index.cfm?cat_id={R:1}&amp;pnumber={R:2}&amp;old=1" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old c_pages" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^c(\d+?)s(\d+?)-(.*?)_(.*?)\.htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="/c_page/index.cfm?id={R:1}&amp;cat_id={R:2}&amp;manuf={R:3}&amp; model={R:4}&amp;old=1" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old c page no model" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^c(\d+?)s(\d+?)-(.*?).htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="/c_page/index.cfm?id={R:1}&amp;cat_id={R:2}&amp;manuf={R:3}&amp; old=1" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b_tb_pages" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^b-(.*?)pn(\d+?)-.*\.htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="tm_guide/cat_view.cfm?cat_id={R:1}&amp;old=1" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old c_tb_pages" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^c-(.*?)-.*\.htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="tm_guide/model.cfm?model_id={R:1}&amp;old=1" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b_model_page" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^b_model_mf(.*?)_mo(.*?)_pn(.*?)-.*\.htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="410" statusReason="Removed" statusDescription="Removed" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b_manuf_sec_all" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^cgi-bin/a_dinamic/b_manuf_sec_all.cfm(.*)" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="http:www.used-line.com" appendQueryString="false" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="result.cfm" stopProcessing="true">

                    <match url="^cgi-bin/a_dinamic/result.cfm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="list_of_categories/categories.cfm" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b model">

                    <match url="^.*_.*_m(.*?).htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="model/model_index.cfm?model_id={R:1}" />

                </rule>

                <rule name="old b model mfr cid">

                    <match url="^.*_.*_2m(.*?)_2mnf(.*?)_2cid(.*?).htm" />

                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="model/model_index.cfm?model_id={R:1}&amp;manuf={R:2}&amp;cat={R: 3}" />

                </rule>

            </rules>

        </rewrite>



    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: coldfusion serves pages which produced an error with statuscode 500 so you have most likely an error anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Like Seybsen said, the 500 status code is returned when there is an error. The error could be happening before you hit the page with the cfheader (so processing is aborted before you can set the status code) or in file_not_found.cfm, wherein the error status code is overriding the statuscode you set.

Answer (score 0):

The primary concern is 500 over here. You can enable "Failed Request Tracking in IIS, as the error 500 is thrown by the webserver. At the same time, analyze the exception/application log for relevant info.

Answer (score -2):

I also would like a more helpful answer on this issue that is still reproducible in CF10 on Windows 2008 R2.

I created a new directory with a blank Application.cfc, with a single Index.cfm page containing the following:  Passing in a status code of anything other than 200 returns with a 500 Error code.

```
<cfparam name="StatusCode" default="200">
<cfparam name="StatusText" default="OK">
<cfif StatusCode EQ "200">
    <cfset variables.message = "Success">
<cfelse>
    <cfset variables.message = StatusText>
</cfif>
<cfheader statuscode="#StatusCode#" statustext="#StatusText#">
<cfoutput>Message:#variables.message#</cfoutput>
<cfabort>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?